# Factorization probability

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm interested in factoring large numbers. I would like to know that if I take a normal laptop and implement for example general or special number sieve and let it run all the time, what would be the probability that I will find a new prime factor for some Fermat number?

Comment: There is a project, see [here](http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html). The probability will be close to zero (assuming that your laptop does not live longer than usual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed probability of finding a factor and depends on the number you select and the processing speed of your computer. It also depends on how long you are going to run it. You can see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Factorization_of_Fermat_numbers) for known factors and how much computational power it actually takes o find them.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean "all the time", then the probability is $1$. Prime factorization is a necessarily finite process. You end up with **some** answer at the end, even if it's that the only prime factor of the number is the number itself.

If you **don't** literally mean "all the time", but perhaps only "a few hours every day for a year", then the probability directly depends on how fast your laptop searches through possible factors.

Comment: And it depends on what really a **new** prime factor is. The standards here are already high.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely. Looking at the page Dietrich linked, you will see that a factorization for $m = 12, k = 7$ discovered by Pervushin and Lucas in 1877 is still "known to be incomplete"! After more than a century! I've been alive almost a century but already three laptops have died on me, and I didn't even subject them to such intense number crunching.

If you're serious about this, you're going to need a good, strong, sturdy desktop computer devoted to running the most efficient algorithm you can get your hands on. And also some kind of back-up system.

Good luck with that.